# Jagged and pixelated edges from bezier taper on bezier bevel (Realistic lightning?)

Tags: bevel, bezier-curves

I was trying to create a realistic lightning but if I use a taper bezier to curve the outer edges of the lightning bezier with a bevel, the edges get really pixelated and jagged. Also the mesh gets disconnected by the end. (See screenshot)

I was trying to put the lightning into another collection and another view layer, and then blur it in the compositor. But the layer with the lightning collection in it (its the only active one on that layer) is empty in the render layer node. But now I am thinking, "Is this even the proper way of fixing the issue?" All I want is for the taper to be not as jagged as it is.

What would be your solution for this?

All help is appreciated.

I included the current animated state of the lightning in my .blend file.

[image: Lightning-jagged-edges]

Blend file: [Blend file Lightning](https://pasteall.org/media/2/a/2a8f1261531c9e525855baac65536c73.blend)